Oracle via port 1522 not 1521
I have an Azure windows server with Oracle Sql Developer installed, I am connecting to Oracle databases on another non azure server.  Most of the time it works OK to establish a connection, but once in a while it fails.  I have checked the network traffic and sometimes sql developer will try and connect on port 1522.  This port is blocked in the firewall, and the organisation wont open it without good cause. The connection definition in sql developer specifies port 1521, the TNSNAMES.ORA file installed by the oracle odbc basic client specifies port 1521 and the tnsnames.ora file installed by the oracle odbc driver specifies port 1521.  So why is a connection being attempted on port 1522?  This is very baffling, any assistance greatly appreciated.

I can't see SQL Developer ever randomly connecting to a different port. Are you maybe connecting to a RAC SCAN listener (docs) on 1521 that is responding with a local listener on 1522 - perhaps because that is misconfigured? Are you seeing different IP addresses in the network traffic, as well as the different port?

The only other optional, intermittent port setting I can think of is for the JDWP debugger. Check in Oracle SQL Developer in the menu Tools --> Preferences --> Debugger. (Although you'd probably already know if the problem only happens when you debug.)
